# background image of a div

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I wrote this little JavaScript to change the background image of a div, after a page load

```
<div id="header">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        var playlist = new Array();
        playlist[0]="background: url('image1') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;";
        playlist[1]="background: url('image2') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;";
        playlist[2]="background: url('image3') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;";      

        var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*playlist.length);

        document.getElementById('header').style = playlist[c];

        -->
</script>

    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

it works fine, but it seems to incompatible with internet explorer/edge. Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you receive from the Edge console?

My guess would be that you need to use `window.onload` or (if using jQuery) `$(document).ready()` to have the script hold off until the page finishes loading.

Comment: set the background directly, not with style

Comment: Unrelated: you seem to be populating playlist[1] twice.

Comment: Try to bind the logic into a page load event, i haven't seen any compatibility or cross-browser error anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does .style work in IE? Have you tried .setAttribute('style', playlist[c]) instead?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've modified the above javascript like so: `    var testa = document.getElementById('header');

    testa.style = playlist[c];
    testa.setAttribute('style', playlist[c]);`

Comment: No worries - I wasn't sure it would work to be honest (and I don't have IE on the machine I'm on now to check) but glad it worked out for you. :)